# How to test for availability of decltype?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I have a C++ module that is compiled both in a C++03 context and in a C++11 context.  When compiling it as C++11, I use `decltype` to find the type of a variable.  In C++03, I can (for my purposes) define `decltype` as a macro in terms of the nonstandard `typeof`:

```
// add zero to get rid of const qualifier on the type
#define decltype(x) typeof((x) + 0)
```

Of course I want to use the original `decltype` if available, and define the macro only if it isn't available.  How do I test for the availability of `decltype`?

I have tried `#ifndef __cpp_decltype` as suggested at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3694.htm, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can use [`Boost.Config`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html) and test `BOOST_NO_CXX11_DECLTYPE`.

Comment: @black: I guess so; I meant to refer to whichever version of C++ corresponds to passing `-std=c++0x` to an older version of gcc.  I'll update the question to say C++03; what matters is that it's pre-`decltype`.

Comment: There are better ways of removing `const`, namely [`std::remove_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_const). Edit: Not available in C++03, but easily implementable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely you should use [Boost.Config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_that_describe_c__11_features_not_supported) and check for `BOOST_NO_CXX11_DECLTYPE` macro.

Answer (score 6):

You may try to use the value of `__cplusplus` predefined macro. For C++11 it is `201103L`. For an older compiler it should be a smaller number.